# Exception while launching my iOS Xamarin App

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, tableview

I'm faced with a problem with my iOS Xamarin App.

Whenever I try to add a tableView in one of my views with the Storyboard, and I launch my app I have always the same error.

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[TableSource initWithCoder:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d6a620

Here is my TableSource code:

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace SmartTransportNatif.iOS2
{
    public partial class TableSource : UITableViewSource
    {

        protected string[] tableItems;
        protected string cellIdentifier = "TableCell";
        HomeTableController home;

        public TableSource (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public TableSource (string[] items, HomeTableController home)
        {
            this.home = home;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return tableItems.Length;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when a row is touched
        /// </summary>
        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UIAlertController okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create("Row Selected", tableItems[indexPath.Row], UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            okAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
            home.PresentViewController(okAlertController, true, null);

            tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called by the TableView to get the actual UITableViewCell to render for the particular row
        /// </summary>
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            // request a recycled cell to save memory
            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier);
            // if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
            if (cell == null)
                cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);

            cell.TextLabel.Text = tableItems[indexPath.Row];

            return cell;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my storyboard:

[image: Storyboard]

Here are the properties of my Tableview in the HomeTableController:

[image: Properties]

Does someone know what is missing or wrong?

Comment: Did you use `TableSource` as the class of your tableView in the storyboard ? If so this is wrong, the class you use must be derived from `UITableView`

Comment: @deadbeef yes the class property is set to TableSource

Comment: You shouldn't be able to set the tablesource as a class of the UITableView because they are not the same thing. You would normally, programatically set the table source by assigning it programatically.